# How I can locate a 'Button' whose span id keeps changing dynamically using Selenium web-driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am automating a *sencha* project.I am finding an obstacle to locate a button named **'START AFE'** whose span id keeps changing dynamically .Attaching the screenshot for the page.

[image]

The highlighted text is the location of the button.So please help me to sort out this difficulty.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can used any one of the below *xpath's* to locate the Button

Method 1:

```
xpath("//button[@id='button-1128-btnE1']//span")
```

Method 2:

```
xpath("//button[@class='x-btn-center']//span[1]")
```

Method 3:

```
xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Start AFE')]")
```

Method 4:

```
xpath("//span[@class='x-btn-inner']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access to this element by xpath:

```
//*[text()="Start AFE")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since, as you say the button's span id keeps changing, so you can **use the innerHTML/text 'Start AFE'** to click on the button.

You can use the below xpath for that:

`//span[.='Start AFE']`

**This will locate the span element having exact innerHTML/text as 'Start AFE'**.